# How to update SPFx extension instances tenant wide automatically?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions

In SPFx, I deployed a listviewcommandset extension to add a context menu option to list items. After adding to app catalogue, I had to manually add the app to the site. And then to update it, I had to delete the app from the site and recycle bin, increase the version number, re deploy the app to the catalogue and then add the app to the site again. Is there a way I can simplify the process and have it so that once I deploy, all sites just get the update automatically?

Answer (score 0):

> As soon as you update the package in the app catalog, all running
> webparts will use the updated manifest, which should point to the
> updated code.

You could refer to the similar question:

[Can I bulk upgrade deployed SPFx web parts?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218054/can-i-bulk-upgrade-deployed-spfx-web-parts)