# SharePoint Online - SPFx - Handling releases to all sites?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, modern-experience, deployment

I have created a few web parts in SPFx that I deploy to my tenant.
If I make changes to the web parts and deploy them to my tenant the changes will show up on all sites.

I am wondering what happens when I increment the version number in `package-solution.json`?

I've noticed that when I do that I have to browse to each site on my tenant and add the updated solution.

So, I've been avoiding incrementing the version number!

Does anyone have a good explanation of how I should be doing things?

Comment: Use tenant scope deployment as given [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/tenant-scoped-deployment). Also check similar thread at: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218054/can-i-bulk-upgrade-deployed-spfx-web-parts

Comment: Excellent thanks once again Ganesh. Can you add that as an answer? Cheers P

Comment: You're welcome @Pete, I have added my comment as an answer below, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the version number of package & deploy in app catalog, you have to update the app you added from site contents on each site.

See, similar thread: [Can I bulk upgrade deployed SPFx web parts?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218054/can-i-bulk-upgrade-deployed-spfx-web-parts)

My suggestion is to use Tenant-scoped solution deployment if you want to add the web parts on multiple SharePoint sites.

Follow this Microsoft documentation for Tenant-scoped solution deployment: [Tenant-scoped solution deployment for SharePoint Framework solutions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/tenant-scoped-deployment)